# Flash CS6 Edit multiple keyframes

Tags: flash

I have symbols on a stage that are in all keyframes.  I want to modify the properties of 2 symbols on all of the keyframes.  Multiple Edit does not work, or I don't know how to make it save the changes. if there is a trick to make this happen, I can't seem to find it.  I select Edit Multiple frames.  Then I select the frames with the slider ends on top of the timeline.  I make the changes and click on the Edit Multiple frames button.  I have 500+ frames and changing all of these properties are driving me nuts....

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is using the Javascript Flash Language (JSFL) which you can use to automate repetitive actions in the Flash authoring tool.

Here's a short script that should do what you want (you need to make sure the layer with your symbol you want to change on it is the only unlocked layer):

```
var doc = fl.getDocumentDOM();
var tl = doc.getTimeline();
var selFrames = tl.getSelectedFrames();

for(var i=selFrames[1];i<selFrames[2];i++)
{
    tl.currentFrame = i;
    tl.setSelectedFrames(i,i+1);
    doc.selectAll();
    var sel = doc.selection[0];
    if(doc.getSelectionRect())
    {
        //set symbol properties to what you want here eg. .x, .y, etc.
        sel.x = 20;
        sel.y = 20;
    }
}
```

you can save this as a file with a JSFL extension and run it from the flash authoring environment.

You can read the whole API of what JSFL is capable of here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/extend/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution in my opinion would be to edit the two symbols from the library & wrap the contents into a sub symbol & apply the properties...

When you put a movieclip onto the stage & apply properties in every frame, behind the scenes (inside addFrameScript) it simply does the same thing again & again. Such repetations really beg for a little of code. The timeline alone is good enough for basic animations, But sprinkling it with even a bit of AS3 could give you good reusable stuff.